# Tdtm Trigger framework

Tags: trigger, education-data-architecture, tdtm

I checked the Npsp and Eda packages, and both have its own flavor of Tdtm framework. So I checked the Tdtm classes in Eda package. But looks like these files are dependent on Eda package.

I can look into the Tdtm classes and remove all the dependencies, but does anyone have the basic Trigger framework which can be deployed to any sandbox environment and then start working on creating triggers?

And if that's not available, is it fine if I can work on removing the dependencies myself and deploy? Is there any license issues which prohibits me to make changes? I love this framework but I would like to have another version of this framework utilizing custom metadata or custom settings.

Comment: This post would be improved by clarifying what TDTM actually stands for.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't to my knowledge a maintained version of TDTM independent of NPSP and EDA.

Both NPSP and EDA are licensed under the [BSD 3-Clause License](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause). Provided you follow that license, you may reuse and modify the code.

---

All that said: TDTM is a fairly old framework, and the state of the art has advanced in a variety of ways since TDTM was designed. You highlight one of them (use of custom settings or custom metadata).

Before you invest labor in building a new, separate TDTM, I'd really encourage you to check out some of the modern trigger frameworks, like Mitch Spano's metadata-driven [Trigger Actions](https://github.com/mitchspano/apex-trigger-actions-framework) framework (just one example).